# Is $L^2(0,T;V_f) \subset L^2(0,T;V)$ closed if $V_f \subset V$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $V$ be an infinite-dimensional separable Hilbert space and let $V_f$ be a subspace of $V$ that is finite dimensional. It follows that $V_f$ is closed.

Is it true that $L^2(0,T;V_f)$ is closed as a set in $L^2(0,T;V)$?

Comment: Use the description of elements in terms of limits of simple functions.

Comment: Do you mean to write the limit point (that I want to show is in $L^2(0,T;V_f)$ for closedness) in terms of limit of simple functions?

Comment: Elements of $L^2(0,T;V_f)$ are *by definition* limits of sequences of simple functions with values in $V_f$. It doesn't matter whether you compute their norms as elements of $L^2(0,T;V_f)$ or $L^2(0,T;V)$, so the embedding is in fact isometric.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't see why that implies closedness. Appreciate it if you please elaborate a bit.

Comment: @Should've been $V_f$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider map
$$
I:L_2((0,T),V_f)\to L_2((0,T),V),\varphi\mapsto \varphi|^{V}
$$
which assotiates to $\varphi$ the same function but with values in larger space i.e. in $V$. Obviously $I$ is linear. It is also isometric. Indeed
$$
\Vert I(\varphi)\Vert_{L_2((0,T),V)}
=\left(\int_0^1\Vert \varphi\Vert_V^2 dt\right)^{1/2}
=\left(\int_0^1\Vert \varphi\Vert_{V_f}^2 dt\right)^{1/2}
=\Vert\varphi\Vert_{L_2((0,T),V_f)}
$$
Since $I$ is isometric it is bounded below, [hence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294895/operatornameranget-is-a-closed-subspace?lq=1) its image is closed. So $L_2((0,T),V_f)\equiv\operatorname{Im}(I)$ is closed in $L_2((0,T),V)$

Comment: If $V_f$ has a different norm to $V$, do you think it still holds? Assuming $V_f \subset V$ is continuous

Comment: it will hold if $$\exists c>0\quad\forall v\in V_f\quad \Vert v\Vert_V\geq c\Vert v\Vert_{V_f}$$

Comment: @Norbert So the subspace is also a banach space. Do you know if there is an easier way to see this other than "closed subspace of Banach space is Banach"?

Comment: I think it is the easiest way