# operator from $\ell_1 $ to $\ell_1$ and density

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I want to solve the following problem, but I am stuck...

> Let $a=(a_n)_n \in \ell_\infty $. Define the linear operator $
>  \displaystyle T : \ell_1 \to \ell_1 $ by $\displaystyle T(x) = a \cdot
>  x , \quad \text{i.e.} \quad T(x)= (a_nx_n)_n $, for $\displaystyle
>  x=(x_n)_n \in \ell_1 $. Prove that:
>
> (i) If $\displaystyle \text{Ker}(T) =\{0\}$ then $T(\ell_1)$ is dense
>   in $\ell_1$
>
> (ii) $\displaystyle T(\ell_1) = \ell_1 $ if and only if $\displaystyle
>  \inf_{n \in \mathbb N} |a_n | > 0 $

I have prove that $\displaystyle \text{ker}(T)=\{0\} $ if and only if $ a_n \neq 0 \quad \forall n \in \mathbb N$.

Any solution or hints would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: If $a_n=0$, then both the sequences $(0,0,....1,0,0...)$ (1 in the nth place) and $(0,0,...0,0...)$ are both mapped to the same thing by $T$.. So what can you say about the kernel in this case?

Comment: @BaronVT: No, I prefer a solution without such tools..

Comment: @user30535: I don't understand about which question youare talking..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove that $\mbox{ker}(T) = \{0\}$ if and only if $a_n \neq 0$ for all $n$, you can  argue as in the finite-dimensional case:

- Suppose first $a_k = 0$ for some $k$ and let $e_k = (0,...,0,1,0,...)$ be the sequence whose $k$-th term is $1$ and whose other terms are $0$. Then $Te_k = (0,...,0,a_k,0,...) = 0$ and thus $\mbox{ker}(T) \neq \{0\}$.
- On the other hand, suppose $a_n \neq 0$ for all $n$. Let $x = (x_k), y = (y_k) \in \ell^1$. If $Tx = Ty$, then $a_kx_k = a_ky_k$ for all $k$. But $a_k \neq 0$ so $x_k = y_k$ for all $k$ and hence $x=y$. Thus $T$ is injective and its kernel is trivial.

Knowing that $a_n \neq 0$ for all $n$, we see that $\frac{1}{k}e_k \in \ell^1$ and $T(\frac{1}{k}e_k) = e_k$. Thus the range of $T$ contains the set
$$\mbox{span} \{e_k: k \in \mathbb{N} \}$$
which is a dense set. This proves the first assertion.

For the second, notice that
$$\|Tx\|_1 \geq \inf_{k} |a_k| \|x\|_1$$
so that $T$ is bounded from below if $\inf_{k} |a_k| > 0$. Therefore, [it has closed range](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294895/operatornameranget-is-a-closed-subspace/295469#295469). Since the range is also dense, it is equal to all of $\ell^1$.

For injective $T$ (which is the case here), the answer linked to above also shows that if the range is closed, then the operator is bounded from below. Thus if $T$ is surjective, there exists a $c > 0$ such that
$$|a_k| = \|a_ke_k\|_1 = |\|Te_k\|_1 \geq c\|e_k\|_1 = c$$
for all $k$. If follows that $\inf_{k} |a_k| \geq c > 0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I know this. As I wrote in the begging I have a proof for this. I am stuck with the questions in the black box...

Comment: @passenger Sorry, I misread your "I have prove" as "I have *to* prove." I will edit the answer to address your concern.

Comment: Thank's! I have just two questions about (ii): (1) for the direction $(\leftarrow)$: the fact that the range is closed doesn't follow from the fact that $T$ is continuous (as bounded linear operator) ? (2) In the other direction, could explain me the fist equality in the equation $|a_k| = \|Te_k\|_1 \geq c\|e_k\|_1 = c$ ? And how this equation follws from the fact that $T$ is surjective ?

Comment: As for your question (1): no it does not. There are counterexamples in many books. For (2): regarding the equality, I've edited in an intermediate step. Regarding the second question, see the link. It shows that if $T$ has closed range (so in particular if it is surjective) then there exists some $c$ such that $\|Tx\| \geq c\|x\|$.

Comment: O.k Now it was me who misread closed graph insted of closed range...! Yes of course you are right... Thank you very much for your time! Your explanation, was very clear!