# For $\langle Tx, x \rangle \geq \|x\|^2$, prove a solution exists for $Tx = y$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

### Edit

I've posted this a couple other times, so I now plan on deleting those, and just using this one.

Here's the original problem:

> $H$ is a real Hilbert space. Let $T: H\longrightarrow H$ be a bounded linear operator on $H$ such that the inner product satisfies
>   $$\langle Tx, x \rangle \geq \|x\|^2 \tag{A}$$
>   Prove that a solution for the equation $Tx = y$ exists for all $y \in H$.

I've been looking at this problem and studying orthogonal complements and the direct sum theorem for a few days now, to no avail, so I suspect there's something very fundamental I don't understand here. Below I'm posting [W. Zhan's proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3192856/262513) that I don't understand, and a couple of starting points of my own. W. Zhan's, as mentioned below, isn't working for me, so I'm starting a bounty. Thank you.

---

### Proof given by W. Zhan

> Note that adjoint of a bounded operator always exists by Riesz Represenation Theorem. So we have 
>   $$ \langle Tx,x \rangle = \langle x, T^*x \rangle  \ge ||x||^2$$ 
>   So $T^*$ is injective. We also have $im T^\perp =  \ker T^*$. Hence, $im T = H$.

I'm not sure what I'm not understanding. I do understand

> So $T^*$ is injective.

and also

> We also have $im T^\perp =  \ker T^*$

but not how those two facts yield the conclusion.

---

Here's a couple starts I've had on my own

### Proof (alternate start 1)

Let $Tx = 0$, then

$$0 = \langle Tx, x\rangle \geq \|x\|^2 \geq 0$$

so $\|x \| = 0$, but by definition of the norm, only if $x = 0$. So $Tx = 0 \iff x = 0$, therefore $T$ is injective. This means $T$ has an inverse linear operator $T^{-1}$.

Now, let $y \in \overline{TH}$. By definition, $y$ is a limit point of $TH$, so there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ in $H$ such that $(Tx_n) \longrightarrow y$. However, $x_n = T^{-1}Tx_n$, which implies

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n = \lim_{n\to \infty} T^{-1}Tx_n  = T^{-1}\lim_{n \to \infty}Tx_n = T^{-1}y$$

... here I think I'm in trouble because I don't know if I can actually show $T^{-1}y$ exits, which I think is equivalent to showint $T^{-1}$ is bounded.

### Proof (alternate start 2)

Here, as W. Zhan pointed out, it's easy to see that $(TH)^\perp = \{0\}$, which implies that $TH$ is dense in $H$. In other words, $\overline{TH} = H$. So all that remains is to show that $TH$ is closed. But this is similar to the argument in my first attempt.

### Discussion

I understand that $T^*$ is injective—because it is a linear operator and $Tx = 0 \implies x = 0$. In fact $T$ is as well. So I believe another option is to show surjectivity of $T$, but I can see how to do that.

Would somebody mind proving the original proposition in a detailed way?

Comment: Hint: you could show that $T$ has trivial kernel.

Comment: The term you want is that your operator $T$ is *coercive*.  The statement you are trying to prove is one form of the Lax-Milgram lemma; I recommend reading section 11.3 of [Kress](https://books.google.com/books?id=Jv_ZBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=kress+numerical+analysis&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQipnuy9rhAhUrwVkKHQ4YBz4Q6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=lax-milgram&f=false) or section 5.3 of [Brezis](https://books.google.com/books?id=GAA2XqOIIGoC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q=Lax-Milgram&f=false).

Answer (score 4):

Note that adjoint of a bounded operator always exists by Riesz Represenation Theorem. So we have
$$ \langle Tx,x \rangle = \langle x, T^*x \rangle  \ge ||x||^2$$
So $T^*x =0 \Rightarrow ||x||=0 $, hence $T^*$ is injective. We also have $im T^\perp =  \ker T^*$. Thus, $im T = H$.

To see why $T$ has closed range, note $||Tx||= \sup_{||y||\le1} |\langle Tx, y \rangle| \ge \langle Tx, x \rangle /||x|| \ge ||x||$.  Then result follows from characterization of closed image. The direction you need is actually already on [MSE.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294895/when-is-the-image-of-a-linear-operator-between-banach-spaces-closed?noredirect=1&lq=1)

EDIT: Here's an easier way to see why $T$ has closed range. Suppose $Tx_n \rightarrow y$, then applying $x=x_n-x_m$ implies $x_n$ is Cauchy. Continuity implies $Tx = y$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the proof a bit more? I'm having a hard time understanding how the injectivity of $T^*$ is used.

Comment: Hi Zduff, edited.

Comment: Hi W. Zhan, I meant that how is it used in relation to the second part, to ensure the result. I'll give you 50 more points if you respond in a very detailed way, suggested in my edited post above. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Zduff, sorry, I did miss out this detail. I added it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative to the existing answers which won't require us to show that $T$ has closed range along the way (obviously we'll get that indirectly from $T$ being surjective). Fix $y \in H$. Note that $Tx = y$ if and only if 
$$\alpha y - \alpha Tx + x = x$$
for $\alpha > 0$. So you're trying to find a fixed point of the operator $\Lambda:x \mapsto \alpha y - \alpha Tx + x$. We can compute
\begin{align}
\|\Lambda x_1 - \Lambda x_2\|^2 =& \| x_1 - x_2 - \alpha T(x_1 - x_2)\|^2
\\ = & \|x_1 - x_2\|^2 + \alpha^2 \|T(x_1 - x_2)\|^2 - 2 \alpha \langle T(x_1 - x_2), x_1 - x_2 \rangle
\\ \leq& \|x_1 - x_2\|^2 + \alpha^2 \|T\|^2 \|x_1 - x_2\|^2 - 2 \alpha \|x_1 - x_2\|^2
\end{align}
If we pick $\alpha = \|T\|^{-2}$, we see that $\lambda$ is a contraction and so the desired $x$ exists by the contraction mapping theorem.

Answer (score 0):

You can show surjectivity of $T$ by using Theorem 0.1 of this [paper](http://www.numdam.org/article/M2AN_1974__8_2_129_0.pdf). What you need to show is

$$ \sup_{x\in H\setminus\{0\}} \langle Tx, y\rangle/\lVert x\rVert \geq c\lVert y\rVert$$

for all $y\in H$ (for some $c>0$). So, for a given $y\in H$ you set $x$ to $y$ and get

$$ \sup_{x\in H\setminus\{0\}} \langle Tx, y\rangle/\lVert x\rVert \geq \langle Ty, y\rangle/\lVert y\rVert \geq \lVert y\rVert$$

which is equivalent to surjectivity of $T$.

Answer (score -1):

We can prove that $T$ is not singular, and from that, the problem is solved.

Assume $T$ is singular. Then there exists a vector $v \not= 0$ such that $Tv = 0$. But then $\langle Tv, v\rangle = 0 < \|v\|^2$ which contradicts our assumption that $\langle Tv, v\rangle \ge \|v\|^2$.

Okay, so now that $T$ is not singular, it has an inverse, implying that $x = T^{-1} y$.

Comment: There are injective bounded operators on infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces that are not surjective. For example, the operator $T:(x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots) \mapsto (0,x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots)$ on $\ell^2$ is injective but there is no $x$ such that $Tx = (1,0,0,\dots)$.