# Spectrum of an operator is approximate point spectrum plus spectrum of dual operator

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, dual-maps

I'm trying to show that given an operator $T \in B(X)$ with $X$ Banach we have $$\sigma(T) = \sigma_{ap}(T) \cup \sigma_p(T') $$

Where $T' \in B(X')$ is the dual operator.

I know that $\sigma(T) = \sigma(T')$ and certainly $\sigma_{ap}(T) \subset \sigma(T)$ so we have $\sigma_{ap}(T) \cup \sigma_p(T') \subset \sigma(T)$ and I'm struggling with the other inclusion.

If we write $R_{\lambda} = {\lambda}I - T$ and now we want to show if $\lambda$ is outside of $ \sigma_{ap}(T) \cup \sigma_p(T')$ then $R_{\lambda}$ is invertible. Here is what I have so far:

- $R_{\lambda}$ has closed image. ($\lambda$ is not in the approx.  point spectrum of $T$)
- $R_{\lambda}$ is injective - the point spectrum of $T$ is contained in the approximate point spectrum of $T$.
- I'd like to show that $R_{\lambda}$ has dense image. We know that $\ker(R_{\lambda}')$ is empty - so if $g \in Y'$ is such that $g(R_{\lambda})(x) = 0$ then $g$ must be zero. I'd like to maybe use the Hahn-Banach theorem on an element in $X$ not in the closure of $\operatorname{im} R_{\lambda}$ or perhaps by extending a functional on $\operatorname{im}R_{\lambda}$ but unfortunately I can't seem to get anywhere with this!

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CASE 1: If $\mathcal{R}(T-\lambda I)$ is not dense, then $\lambda\in\sigma_{p}(T')$.

CASE 2: $\mathcal{R}(T-\lambda I)=X$.

2a. $T-\lambda I$ is injective, which forces $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$ to be continuous and, hence, $\lambda\in\rho(T)$; or

2b. $T-\lambda I$ is not injective, which gives $\lambda \in\sigma_{p}(T)$.

CASE 3: $\mathcal{R}(T-\lambda I)$ is dense but $\mathcal{R}(T-\lambda I)\ne X$.

3a. $T-\lambda I$ is not injective and, hence, $\lambda\in\sigma_{p}(T)$.

3b. $T-\lambda I$ is injective. In this case $T-\lambda I$ is not continuously invertible because $\mathcal{R}(T-\lambda I)$ is not dense, which means $\lambda\in\sigma_{ap}(T)$.

That covers all cases: $\sigma(T)\subseteq\sigma_{p}(T')\cup\sigma_{p}(T)\cup\sigma_{ap}(T)$.

Comment: Thank you for this answer - I'm probably missing something obvious but how did you deduce the first line in case 1? Also is it not true that $\sigma_p(T) \subset \sigma_{ap}(T)$

Comment: Does the first case follows from the Hahn-Banach theorem? As in then we would have the image of $T-\lambda I$ being a proper subspace and so there is a non-zero functional that is zero when restricted to the image and hence in the kernel of the dual operator?

Comment: @Wooster : Yes, the Hahn-Banach Theorem gives you the first case. This definition of $\sigma_{ap}$ can differ, but you see the actual cases from what I wrote. So apply your definition of $\sigma_{ap}$, which I assume does include $\sigma_{p}$ based on the statement you were asked to show.

Answer (score 0):

By definition $\sigma_{A P}(T) \subset \sigma(T)$, so it is enough to prove

**Claim 1:** $\sigma_P\left(T'\right) \subset \sigma(T)$
and
**Claim 2:** $\sigma(T) \setminus \sigma_{A P}(T) \subset \sigma_P\left(T'\right)$

**Proof of Claim 1:** Let $\lambda \in \sigma_P\left(T'\right)$. Then there exists $f \in X^*$ with $f \neq 0$ so that $T' f=\lambda f$, i.e. so that for every $x \in X$
$$
0=\left(T' f-\lambda f\right)(x)=f(T x)-\lambda f(x)=f(T x-\lambda x) .
$$

Hence the restriction $\left.f\right|_Y$ of $f$ to the image $Y=(T-\lambda \mathrm{I}) X$ of $T-\lambda \mathrm{I}$ is zero, so as $f\ne0$, we must have that $\bar{Y} \neq X$. Thus the image of $T-\lambda \mathrm{I}$ is not dense in $X$ so $\lambda \in \sigma(T)$.

**Proof of Claim 2:** Let $\lambda \in \sigma(T) \setminus \sigma_{A P}(T)$. Then as $\lambda$ is not an approximate eigenvalue of $T$ we know that $T-\lambda\mathrm{I}$ is bounded below, by the Lemma the image $Y=(T-\lambda \mathrm{I})(X)$ is closed. At the same time $Y$ cannot be all of $X$ as otherwise $T-\lambda \mathrm{I}$ would have a bounded inverse, so $Y$ is a proper closed subspace of $X$. We can thus apply Hahn-Banach, to conclude that there exists some $f \in X^*$ with $f \neq 0$, so that $\left.f\right|_Y=0$. This implies that $T'(f)=\lambda f$ and thus that $\lambda \in \sigma_P\left(T'\right)$ since for every $x \in X$ we have $T x-\lambda x \in Y$ and thus $\left(T'(f)-\lambda f\right)(x)=f(T x-\lambda x)=0$.$\quad\square$

**Lemma.** Let $X$ be a Banach space. If $S\in B(X)$ is bounded below then $SX ⊂ X$ is closed.
Proof:([When is the image of a linear operator closed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26071/when-is-the-image-of-a-linear-operator-closed))
Given any sequence $y_n$ in $S X$ which converges $y_n \rightarrow y$ to some $y \in X$, we let $x_n \in X$ be so that $S x_n=y_n$. We then note that as $\left(y_n\right)$ is a Cauchy-sequence, the assumption ($\exists \delta>0$ so that for all $x \in X$ we have $\|S x\| \geq \delta\|x\|$.) implies that
$$
\left\|x_n-x_m\right\| \leq \delta^{-1}\left\|S\left(x_n-x_m\right)\right\|=\delta^{-1}\left\|y_n-y_m\right\| \underset{n, m \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0,
$$
i.e. that also $\left(x_n\right)$ is Cauchy and thus, as $X$ is complete, that $x_n \rightarrow x$ for some $x \in X$. As $S$ is continuous we thus get that $y=\lim y_n=\lim S x_n=S x \in S X$.